# Video Background for Safari 11.0

Tags: php, wordpress, safari, mp4, blocking

I am currently having an issue with any background videos playing in Safari. Below are some links. It shows the Black Background that doesn't display the Background Video we have in place for some of our posts.

I have them all set in a custom Post Type in the Backend of of our WordPress websites using the WCK plugin and created a custom fields creator for our videos. To print them out, I have them set in the single-sponsored post PHP file.

Here is the code to link it altogether.

[Code For the Entire Video Encoding in PHP in our Single Post File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4Y9.png) com/6foGw.png

Here are some links to what posts I am talking about. (Make sure to be in Safari to get the bug)

http://landscapemanagement.net/sponsoredcontent/how-to-get-the-most-out-of-any-trenching-project/

http://www.mypmp.net/sponsoredcontent/how-to-repel-birds-from-any-environment/

Is there a workaround for this as it is just displaying to black in the Safari Browser?

Please let me know whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

Review the changes to autoplay video in Safari that are referenced here: https://bitmovin.com/play-not-play-new-autoplay-policies-safari-11-chrome-64/

Here's the gist of how to detect if autoplay is available using JS:

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();
if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(_ => {
        // Autoplay started!
    }).catch(error => {
        // Autoplay was prevented.
        // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
    });
}
```

Comment: Found out that it was all prevented. Is there a possible workaround for the video to play at all? Or is this going to be more so a Safari replacement type of thing? Like maybe add a play button for Safari view only? Just trying to seek the solution at this point. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @DylanHamilton This functionality was added for the user to have control over autoplay videos in Safari. There's actually a flag they can change based on their preferences, I believe. So, to answer your question, the code I copied in above would be how you'd detect whether the browser allows autoplay video, and if it doesn't, how to add in a play/pause button for your video or another alternative based on your needs.